# Missing /dev/kvm while kernel module kvm.ko and kvm-intel.ko are both loaded

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, qemu, kvm

The `uname -a` shows:

> Linux localhost 2.6.39-gentoo-r3-nsfocus+ #52 SMP PREEMPT Wed Feb 12
>   15:37:56 CST 2014 i686 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
>   GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

And I have already open the Intel VT on BIOS. The /proc/cpuinfo file content:

> flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge
>   mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx
>   rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts xtopology nonstop_tsc
>   aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl **vmx** smx est tm2 ssse3
>   cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt aes xsave avx lahf_lm arat
>   epb xsaveopt pln pts dts tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid

When I run qemu, the output is:

```
>./qemu-system-x86_64 -smp 1 -m 1024 -enable-kvm -vnc :1 -usb -usbdevice tablet -hda /opt/nsfocus/sda1/win2008r2.qcow2
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory
```

I already **have tried** compile kvm and kvm-intel into kernel instead of as kernel modules, the result is the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try to add it manually:

```
mknod /dev/kvm c 10 232
```

Comment: It works!!! Thanks very much. Could you explain why the /dev/kvm was not created automatically?

Comment: To be honest - it is hard to say for me. It may depends on linux distribution. Maybe linux installer didn't create it? I just already have it on my system.

Comment: Could you give me the version of your linux kernel? Maybe it's a kernel version and kvm's bug I think.

Comment: I've got 3.2.28 version.